# How to Mock config file in .Net Core with xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-service-fabric, xunit.net

I want to mock the config file values in .NET Core.

I am using xUnit for unit test. I am using application insight.

I use config file for configuration. Now I want to mock that *.cs* config file in my unit test case.

```
var configurationPackage = statelessServiceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
var appInsightsSection = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["AppInsightsConfig"];
var appInsightsInstrumentationKey = appInsightsSection.Parameters["AppInsights_InstrumentationKey"].Value;
```

`var configurationPackage` is coming *null* in testing.

So I want to mock this

```
statelessServiceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
```

Comment: Include how you try to test this. There is currently not enough context to be able to provide you with useful feedback.

Comment: What is `statelessServiceContext` ? Probably you could resolve it, or its property `CodePackageActivationContext` using dependency injection? Then you could register alternative implementations / configurations for unit tests during its initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the [OSS](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks)/[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.Mocks/) package 'ServiceFabric.Mocks'.

For an example, check [this](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/master/test/ServiceFabric.Mocks.Tests/ServiceTests/ConfigurationPackageTests.cs) unit test.

Relevant code:

```
using static ServiceFabric.Mocks.MockConfigurationPackage;
[..]

//build ConfigurationSectionCollection
var configSections = new ConfigurationSectionCollection();
//Build ConfigurationSettings
var configSettings = CreateConfigurationSettings(configSections);
//add one ConfigurationSection
ConfigurationSection configSection = CreateConfigurationSection("AppInsightsConfig");
configSections.Add(configSection);
//add one Parameters entry
ConfigurationProperty parameter = CreateConfigurationSectionParameters("AppInsights_InstrumentationKey", "some value");
configSection.Parameters.Add(parameter);
//Build ConfigurationPackage
ConfigurationPackage configPackage = CreateConfigurationPackage(configSettings, nameof(configPackage.Path));
var context = new MockCodePackageActivationContext(
                "fabric:/MockApp",
                "MockAppType",
                "Code",
                "1.0.0.0",
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                @"C:\logDirectory",
                @"C:\tempDirectory",
                @"C:\workDirectory",
                "ServiceManifestName",
                "1.0.0.0")
            {
                ConfigurationPackage = configPackage
            };
[..]
//pass the `MockCodePackageActivationContext` to the Service constructor.
```