# How do you Mock CodePackageActivationContext for Config and Data Package using ServiceFabric.Mocks Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, azure-service-fabric

This is a followup question to [Specific questions about unit-testing Service Fabric Applications using Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334180/specific-questions-about-unit-testing-service-fabric-applications-using-mocks)

I am using Xunit along with ServiceFabric.Mocks to Unit Test my application.
My Service Fabric application looks like this:

```
namespace SearchService
{
    internal sealed class SearchServiceClass : StatelessService
    {
        //variables defined followed by constructor
        private string jsonStr;
        public SearchServiceClass(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            try
            {
                var section = Context.CodePackageActivationContext
                .GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
                .Settings
                .Sections[_configSectionName];
                var _parameters = section.Parameters.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Name, kv => kv.Value);
                //_parameters used to set further variables in the constructor
                var dataPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext
                .GetDataPackageObject("Data");
                jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(dataPackage.Path + @"\data.json");
                //removed code for brevity
            }
            catch
            {
                //exception handling code
                throw;
            }
        }
        
        public bool IsDataJsonLoaded
        {
            get
            {
                return !(jsonStr == null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The initial Unit Test looks like this:

```
using Xunit;
using ServiceFabric.Mocks;

namespace App.UnitTests
{
    public class SearchServiceTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SearchServiceClassConstructor()
        {
            var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
            //assert:
            Assert.True(searchServiceClass.IsDataJsonLoaded);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this Unit test, the "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception is thrown. This is arising because in the Unit Test setup, the "Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetDataPackageObject("Data");" returns null to "dataPackage". And hence the Assertion on the IsDataJsonLoaded returns 'False'.

I searched around on Stackoverflow and found this answer most closely answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803921/14761454 But on using the code from this answer, my Unit test looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServiceFabric.Mocks;
using SearchService;
using Xunit;
using static ServiceFabric.Mocks.MockConfigurationPackage;

namespace App.UnitTests
{
    public class SearchServiceTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SearchServiceClassConstructor()
        {
            //Arrange
            const string path = "../SearchService/PackageRoot/Data"; //The Data Package lives in the SearchService project, specifically PackageRoot/Data
            const string name = "Data";
            const string version = "1.0.0";
            const string serviceManifestName = "SearchServicePkg";
            const string serviceManifestVersion = "1.0.0";
            var dataPackageDescription = MockDataPackage.CreateDataPackageDescription(name, version, serviceManifestName, serviceManifestVersion, path);
            var dataPackage = MockDataPackage.CreateDataPackage(path, dataPackageDescription);

            //build ConfigurationSectionCollection
            var configSections = new ConfigurationSectionCollection();
            //Build ConfigurationSettings
            var configSettings = CreateConfigurationSettings(configSections);
            //add one ConfigurationSection
            ConfigurationSection configSection = CreateConfigurationSection("SearchServiceConfigSection");
            configSections.Add(configSection);

            //add one Parameters entry
            ConfigurationProperty parameter = CreateConfigurationSectionParameters(nameof(parameter.Name), nameof(parameter.Value));
            configSection.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            var Context = MockCodePackageActivationContext.Default;

            var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
            //Act
            Context.SetDataPackage(dataPackage);
            //Assert:
            Assert.True(searchServiceClass.IsDataJsonLoaded);
        }
        
    }
}
```

But now the compiler throws up errors saying the "ConfigurationSection" and "ConfigurationProperty" could not be found in the namespace.

Am I on the right track? Will I be completely able to mock the Config and Data Packages from the actual StatelessService in the Unit Test environment if I proceed like this. How do I fix these errors first?

Edit: based on the response by LoekD below, I have updated to ServiceFabric.Mocks v4.2.8, and implemented additional code to mock the Data package. But the NullReferenceException still persists. This error corresponds to the "dataPackage.Path" line in the constructor of the SearchServiceClass. While now there is a separate "MockCodePackageActivationContext.Default;" context and a separate "MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default" context passed to the constructor of SearchServiceClass in the Unit Test, the CodePackageActivation doesn't exist within the Mock StatelessServiceContext. Not sure if that makes sense... but essentially, this seems to lead to the "NullReferenceException" in the dataPackage.Path reference in the constructor. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try using :https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/Iot.Mocks/MockCodePackageActivationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track!

- Step 1.

The classes `ConfigurationSection` and `ConfigurationProperty` are in SF namespace `System.Fabric.Description`. Add a `using` for the namespace

- Step 2.

Please upgrade to ServiceFabric.Mocks v4.2.8. This adds support to mock the `DataPackage` property on `MockCodePackageActivationContext`.
See [this page](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/6c8705671102d22c2373f69967ada783222c3c98/test/ServiceFabric.Mocks.Tests/ServiceTests/ConfigurationPackageTests.cs#L14) for an example.

- Step 3.

Use the created context as a constructor argument.
Change this code:

```cs
var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
```

into this:

```cs
var activationContext = new MockCodePackageActivationContext(
                "fabric:/MockApp",
                "MockAppType",
                "Code",
                "1.0.0.0",
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                @"C:\logDirectory",
                @"C:\tempDirectory",
                @"C:\workDirectory",
                "ServiceManifestName",
                "1.0.0.0")
            {
                ConfigurationPackage = configPackage
            };
activationContext.SetDataPackage(dataPackage);

var newUri = new Uri("fabric:/MockApp/SearchService");
var serviceTypeName = "SearchServiceType";
var partitionId = Guid.NewGuid();
var replicaId = long.MaxValue;

var serviceContext = MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Create(activationContext, serviceTypeName, newUri, partitionId, replicaId);
var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(serviceContext);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the namespace issue first. Then I saw the code to mock the "DataPackage", implemented the same in my Unit Test. What I don't get is how to fix the "NullReferenceException" I get when I run the Unit Test. This error corresponds to the "dataPackage.Path" line in the constructor of the SearchServiceClass. While now there is a separate "MockCodePackageActivationContext.Default;" context and a separate "MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default" context passed to the constructor of  SearchServiceClass in the Unit Test, the CodePackageActivation doesn't exist..

Comment: ..(continued) within the Mock StatelessServiceContext. Not sure if that makes sense... but essentially, this seems to lead to the "NullReferenceException" in the dataPackage.Path reference in the constructor. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please take a look and let me know if the code I am trying to mock in my constructor can actually be mocked?

Comment: Instead of the `Default` instance, use your own customized `Context` instance as a constructor argument (see above).

Comment: Thanks @LoekD. I was trying precisely that... on doing Step 3, I get the following error: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ServiceFabric.Mocks.MockCodePackageActivationContext' to 'System.Fabric.StatelessServiceContext'.

Comment: I managed to get the Data package working, even without doing Step 3. But the corresponding Config Package references in the Service being unit tested still returns NullReferenceException errors. Have gone over it line by line and compared the same to your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803921/14761454. But not able to resolve it.

Comment: sorry, I mixed up service context and code package activation context, changed my code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I was really scratching my head about this one.